# Do Native apps have access to HTML5 API's

Tags: vue.js, voice-recognition, webspeech-api, vue-native

I am building a language translation flashcard web app. I will have a PWA version on the website and then a native app in the Play Store and Windows Store.. maybe even Apple Store eventually. First time looking to build a native app or pseudo native app.

The app currently uses the Web Speech API and Voice Recognition API in HTML5. These API's have support on Chrome and Android Web Browser. It appears they are in progress for Firefox and some other browsers.

Since the best functionality of the app is built upon these browser based API's..

**I am wondering if I choose to use Vue Native instead of Cordova/Phonegap, how is it possible to access these HTML5 APIs natively or is there a native solution?**

Comment: There's [this blog](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-speech-recognition).

Comment: I suppose there's enough native modules for this then... cool ^^